# Error sending Test Mailing for users that do not have SA rights in Tridion CMS

Tags: outbound-email, audience-manager

We are getting the below error while trying to send test emails to all users other than SA users.
please suggest if it is the timeout that is the issue or is there something else that needs to be configured here.

> This request operation sent to net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/201501/netTcp did not receive a reply within the configured timeout (00:01:00).
>
> The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
>
> This may be because the service is still processing the operation or because the service was unable to send a reply message.
>
> Please consider increasing the operation timeout (by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property) and ensure that the service is able to connect to the client.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems pretty clear: it times out when trying to talk to the Core Service on the specified URL. Of course, that might just mean that the URL is wrong.

Double-check that the Core Service URL is correct (net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/201501/netTcp). If not, it's configured in OutboundEmail.xml on your Content Manager machine.

Comment: It throws this error for non-'SA' users. Users that are SA, are able to send Test mails.

Comment: Yes, I read that. I don't think that rules out configuration issues, though.

Comment: Hi Peter, I get the same error and it works for another mailings Test Emal but it throws this error for a new PT template which takes a little longer to process it has long logic behind it. I checked the core service url in OBE.xml and its fine. any other suggestion?

Comment: I also have checked the core service timeout settings in various Tridion configs and we have set it for 01:00:00. which was tested and working earlier.

Comment: @VikasKumar, To summarize; are you facing the issue with new PT (for SA and non-SA users) or issue with all for non-SA users? This will help isolate issue with Tridion (template vs config) vs. system (security vs. configuration).

Comment: @Shiva I had fixed it by adding timeout settings to the AM specific services bindings. Ex: TestMailing etc. I will try to pull some of my notes on bindings and get u.

Comment: Vikas please can you mention more details on what changes you did to fix the issue.